# Sumifs for filtering on text value of numbers

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sumifs

Trying to use `SUMIFS` from a data dump (i.e. can't manipulate the raw data). One of the criteria of the `SUMIFS` is to filter on the periods, where periods are in text value 01,02,03...10,11,12. I want to filter on such as "Period is less than 3". How would i do that?

Tried multiple ways such as `SUMIFS(Range, Period, "<=03")` and all sorts of variations but just won't work.

Can someone please help out?

Comment: I found an old post showing how here: https://exceljet.net/formula/sumifs-with-multiple-criteria-and-or-logic... you give the SUMIFS an array, then wrap it in sum: 
     =SUM(SUMIFS(sum_range,criteria_range,{"01","02", "03"}))

Answer (score 1):

> I want to filter on such as "Period is less than 3". How would i do
>   that?

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(Range*1<3))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The answer from JvdV is definitely a good one but if you do want to use SUMIF you can try to add a helper column to the original data set to convert the periods from text to number using **NUMBERVALUE** function as shown in the picture below. Then your SUMIF function will work fine by referencing to the helper column for periods.

[image]

Cheers :)